# OSX CPU and Memory monitor

Tags: macos

I believe there is a memory leak in the version of IntelliJ that I'm using and some other misbehaving apps. I'd like to have a desktop widget of some sort in OSX that I can, at a glance, check current CPU and memory usage.

Right now I'm using Activity Monitor, but a widget seems like it would be more convenient and accessible.

Comment: Or there's always `top`...

Comment: How are you going to correctly diagnose a memory leak, as distinct from simply 'using memory' & how is this going to fix it, short of filing a bug report with the appropriate developers?

Comment: I'm not planning to fix or diagnose a memory leak. but I would like to visually see that my system is running out of memory and might be slowing down my environment.  I would like a workaround, like restarting IntelliJ or some other unexpected offender.

Comment: Then Activity Monitor would be your best bet, as it will show memory pressure, as well as individual usage. If you don't have the desktop real estate to keep it visible in a corner, assign it to a fixed space & use key commands to flick across to it & back